# How do I use my SSH keys for Git on another remote server?

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys

I am having issues getting Git to work on a newly setup remote server. The actual server itself I have turned off password authentication and am using key authentication. They key the server uses is the same key I use for git.

I added the key to the server using `ssh-copy-id user@4xx.xx.xx.xx` from my local machine, and then `sudo chmod -R 700 ~/.ssh && chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote machine.

Now to git. I am trying to run `git clone git@github.com:user/some-repo.git` from the remote server and get the following log:

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'xx.xxx.xx.xx' to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

How do I get this to work? Does the private key also need to be copied onto this machine? How do I go about doing this?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear which machine you are running git from. Are you saying you ssh from a local machine to the remote server and then on the remote server you are trying to run git?

Comment: Sorry. From the remote. Edited the question

Answer (score 1):

For your case, will be correct to generate a new ssh key, use [ssh-keygen](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/keygen/) flow, and [add into your Git account](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) as a new access key.

Comment: Oh damn. Didn't' think of this. Forgot I can have more than one key. That makes the most sense. Thanks